# buffer getting fully filled before consuming

Tags: java, synchronization, producer-consumer

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;enter code here

public class shared {
private int [] buffer;
private int capacity;
Object lock;//=new Object();
int count=0;
int i,j;
//int i=0,j=0;

public shared(int capacity){
    this.capacity = capacity;
    buffer = new int[capacity];
     i=0;
     j=0;
     lock = new Object();
    //for(int k=0;k<capacity;k++){
        //buffer[k]=0;
    //}
}

public void producer() throws InterruptedException {
    //synchronized(lock){
    while(true){
        synchronized(lock){
    Random rn = new Random();
    int number = rn.nextInt(100);
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    while(count==capacity){
        try{
            System.out.println("BUffer is full");
        lock.wait();

        }catch(InterruptedException e){

        }

        //System.out.println("buffer is full");
    }
    System.out.println("producing" + number);
    buffer[i] = number;
    i = (i+1)%capacity;
    count++;
    lock.notifyAll();
}
    }
}


public void consumer(){
    //synchronized(lock){
    while(true){
        synchronized(lock){
    while(count==0){
        try{
            lock.wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){



        }
    }
        //int a = buffer.get(0);
        //buffer.remove(0);
        int consumed = buffer[j];
        System.out.println("consuming" + consumed);
        j=(j+1)%capacity;
        count--;
        lock.notifyAll();
        if((consumed%2)==0){
            System.out.println("the number displayed by the consumer is " + consumed);
            }
    }
    }
}
}

public class producer implements Runnable {
shared h;


public producer(shared s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    h=s;
}

public void run(){
    //for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    try {
        h.producer();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
public class consumer implements Runnable {
shared h;

    public consumer(shared s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        h=s;
    }
    public void run(){
        //for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        h.consumer();

    }
    }
    public class implement {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException{
        shared s = new shared(10);
        Thread pro1 = new Thread(new producer(s));
        Thread con1 = new Thread(new consumer(s));
        pro1.start();
        con1.start();
        pro1.join();
        con1.join();
    }
    }
```

This is the entire code that I have written. The problem that I am getting is that my buffer is getting entirely full first then it is getting consumed. I want it to be consumed randomly i.e. when the first element fills up it might get get consumed or after 3-4 elements filled up.

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced your experiment and checked that, in fact, the producer thread fills the buffer before the consumer comes in. And that's because only when the buffer is full, the producer calls `wait` to give the consumers a chance.

The behaviour in a multi-threaded environment is always something random. Surely when the execution exits from the producer's synchronized block, the next iteration comes so quickly that it enters again in the block before other threads have a chance to.

If you want to produce and consume with an random ratio, I suggest you other means:

- First, move the `sleep` out of the synchronized block.
- Or else, do always a *wait first-notify last* into your producer loop, but performing a random number of inserts between them.